# codehaus sonarqube component moved to sonarsource

Tags: sonarqube, repository

I've been trying to get a legacy application to start working with code coverage tools and Sonarqube this week and I've been struggling.  I noticed when comparing 2 sample 'apps' I've downloaded and modified to get the basics working  that they are using different group Ids for similar components.  Especially sonar-jacoco-listeners.

so one is using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the other

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
      <version>3.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If I look at this web article http://www.javaworld.com/article/2892227/open-source-tools/codehaus-the-once-great-house-of-code-has-fallen.html & compare the versions (codehaus stops at it 3.2 and sonarsource picks up at 3.4) it looks obvious that the sonarsource group took over & continued the management of this component.

I wondered if anyone could confirm that this is just a direct continuation with a different group ?  And also if there is anything I should watch out for ?  It seems clear that one leads into the other bit is there a place I should be looking to see this history clearly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `org.sonarsource.*` groups are indeed a direct continuation of the `org.codehaus.sonar*` ones.

This is true for almost any component you'll find out there:

- libraries - like the JaCoCo one
- SonarQube plugins
- SonarQube API
- SonarQube itself